# Removing elements with a little bit of logic

Tags: javascript, jquery

On a closing event, I would like to do the following:

- If there is only 1 input field: Do nothing
- If there are more than 1 input fields and the value of none of them is empty: Do nothing
- If there are more than 1 input fields and there is at least one field that has a value: Remove all other fields which do not have  any values
- If there are more than one input fields and none of them has a value: Delete all input fields except the first one

This is what I have so far:

```
$(document).on('closing', '#sidebar', function (e) {
    if ($('#sidebar input').size() > 1) {
        $('#sidebar input').each(function(i){
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                $(this).remove();
            }
        })
    }
});
```

This script will remove all input fields which have no values but that's not exactly what I want?!

Comment: do not use size(), use length

Comment: So your only missing point is the last one, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you just want to compare the empty length to all the inputs.

```js
$(".x").each(function() {
  var wrapper = $(this),  //element that holds the inputs
    allInputs = wrapper.find("input"),  //get all inputs
    emptyInputs = allInputs.filter(function() {  //filter out the empty inputs
      return !this.value.length  //if there is no length it is false so we make false true
    });

  if (allInputs.length === emptyInputs.length) {  //if lengths are equal, remove the first one
    emptyInputs = emptyInputs.slice(1);
  }
  emptyInputs.remove();  //remove the empty elements

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>All empty</h3>
<div class="x">
  <input type="text" value="">
  <input type="text" value="">
  <input type="text" value="">
  <input type="text" value="">
  <input type="text" value="">
</div>

<h3>Some empty</h3>
<div class="x">
  <input type="text" value="">
  <input type="text" value="">
  <input type="text" value="3">
  <input type="text" value="">
  <input type="text" value="5">
</div>

<h3>None empty</h3>
<div class="x">
  <input type="text" value="1">
  <input type="text" value="2">
  <input type="text" value="3">
  <input type="text" value="4">
  <input type="text" value="5">
</div>
```

So applying the answer to your code:

```
$(document).on('closing', '#sidebar', function (e) {
  var wrapper = $(this),  //element that holds the inputs
    allInputs = wrapper.find("input"),  //get all inputs
    emptyInputs = allInputs.filter(function() {  //filter out the empty inputs
      return !this.value.length  //if there is no length it is false so we make false true
    });

  if (allInputs.length === emptyInputs.length) {  //if lengths are equal, remove the first one
    emptyInputs = emptyInputs.slice(1);
  }
  emptyInputs.remove();  //remove the empty elements
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Get all empty input fields using [`filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter) method and compare the size of both empty and original array to remove element. Where use  [`slice()`](https://api.jquery.com/slice/) method to get all element except the first.

```
$(document).on('closing', '#sidebar', function(e) {
  // cache all inputs
  var $inputs = $('#sidebar input');

  // check inputs count is greater than 1
  if ($inputs.length > 1) {
    // filter out empty iput fields
    $empty = $inputs.filter(function(i) {
      return this.value == '';
    });
    // check all input fileds are empty
    if ($empty.length == $inputs.length)
    // if all are emty get input element except 
    // first and remove
      $empty.slice(1).remove();
    // else remove all empty inputs
    else
      $empty.remove();
  }
});
```

```js
$('.x').each(function() {
  var $inputs = $('input', this);
  if ($inputs.length > 1) {
    $empty = $inputs.filter(function(i) {
      return this.value == '';
    });
    if ($empty.length == $inputs.length)
      $empty.slice(1).remove();
    else
      $empty.remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>All empty</h3>
<div class="x">
  <input type="text" value="">
  <input type="text" value="">
  <input type="text" value="">
  <input type="text" value="">
  <input type="text" value="">
</div>

<h3>Some empty</h3>
<div class="x">
  <input type="text" value="">
  <input type="text" value="">
  <input type="text" value="3">
  <input type="text" value="">
  <input type="text" value="5">
</div>

<h3>None empty</h3>
<div class="x">
  <input type="text" value="1">
  <input type="text" value="2">
  <input type="text" value="3">
  <input type="text" value="4">
  <input type="text" value="5">
</div>
<h3>Single</h3>
<div class="x">
  <input type="text" value="">
</div>
```

Comment: I did not downvote, but if the first is empty and second has a value, this would not meet the OPs needs.

Comment: I did downvote because the OP very clearly laid out the requirements in a set of bullet points, and this doesn't meet those requirements.

Answer (score 0):

please check this code , i have add this code for load function so you can change as like you want

```
 $(function () {
    if ($('#sidebar input').length > 1) {
        var j = 0;
        $('#sidebar input').each(function (i) {
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                $(this).remove();
            } else if (j == 0) {
                j = 1;
            }
            else {
                $(this).remove();
            }
        })
    }
});
```

and you can use this simple code for your issue

```
 $(document).on('closing', '#sidebar', function(e) {
    if ($('#sidebar input').length > 1) {
        var j = 0;
        $('#sidebar input').each(function (i) {
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                $(this).remove();
            } else if (j == 0) {
                j = 1;
            }
            else {
                $(this).remove();
            }
        })
    }
});
```

i think it will work

Answer (score 0):

You can find out the length of the empty and non empty input elements and compare the length with the total length of inputs.

```js
var inputList = $("#sidebar input");

if (inputList.length > 1) {

  var notEmpty = inputList.filter(function(elem) {
    return $(this).val() !== ""
  });
  
  var empty = inputList.filter(function(elem) {
    return $(this).val() === ""
  });

  if (notEmpty.length > 0 && inputList.length != notEmpty.length) {
  
    $(empty).remove();
    
  }
  else if(notEmpty.length == 0){
    
    inputList.not(":first").remove();
    
  }
    

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sidebar">
  <input type="text" value="">
  <input type="text" value="">
  <input type="text" value="">
</div>
```